# change response after login or registration

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

i want return a response json after login. i try use:

```
public function login(Request $request){

        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            return response()->json([

                'data' => $request,
                'success' => true,
            ]);
        }



    }
}
```

but always, the Auth::attempt, return false.

what am I doing wrong?
or, how i can change the code of the simple auth of lavarel lest redirect, just return a json response.

thanks.

Comment: If you are using Laravels auth system, the passwords are hashed. Passing in your password should be written as bcrypt($request->password)

Comment: @RobFonseca, where I need add the bcrypt($request->password)?

Comment: Right were you are currently using $request->password in the Auth::attempt method. Just wrap it in bcrypt()

Comment: @RobFonseca, still returning false :/

Comment: Can you provide an existing user credentials?

Comment: @RobFonseca the password credential passed to attempt is always the plain text version. The user provider looks for the user based on all the credentials except for password, which if found will then do a hash check of the plain vs the record's hashed password.

Comment: You are correct. I realized that after I posted